# Passing functions into css prop in emotion js

Tags: emotion

I'm playing with Emotion and really like the compositional style, specially moving to the `css` prop over the `styled` system available in styled components. One thing I haven't figured out is how to use functions inside the `css` prop layer. Doing the following results in

```
index.js:2177 Functions that are interpolated in css calls will be stringified.
If you want to have a css call based on props, create a function that returns a css call like this
let dynamicStyle = (props) => css`color: ${props.color}`
It can be called directly with props or interpolated in a styled call like this
let SomeComponent = styled('div')`${dynamicStyle}`
```

The problem is I very specifically don't want to use the `styled` system here.

Here's some example code

```
const styleFont = (
  props: styleFontProps = {
    fontFamily: 'helvitica',
  }
) => css`
  font-family: ${props.fontFamily};
`;

const paragraph = css`
  ${styleFont};
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
`;
```

And then of course calling this later in the return

```
<div css={paragraph}>Some paragraph text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in emotion you need to include the parens even if the paremeters are empty. See below.

```
const paragraph = css`
  ${styleFont()};
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
`;
```

Comment: Note: JavaScript requires parentheses to execute a function. That's just the syntax.